# Automatically assign Directory permissions to newly created files inside a Directory in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, permissions

My directory (logs/) has 777 Permissions, whenever a new log file is created its has default permission 644. I want to give the same permission as the directory ie. 777 to the log files which gets generated.

Comment: There is no general way to force permissions for all created files. Please [edit] your question and add more details. What program creates the log files? Maybe the program has options to control the log file permissions. Maybe you have to set `umask` for the process.

Comment: Why on earth would you need logs to be executable?

Comment: @tink Please ignore the permission digit. and look at the title

Comment: As Bodo said: that can't be (trivially) done.  You could conceivably writer a script using inotifywait ...